# Showing that $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^8-4x^6+9x^4-5x^2+1}{x^{12}-10x^{10}+37x^8-42x^6+26x^4-8x^2+1}\,{dx} = \frac{1}{2}\pi$ by real analysis

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^8-4x^6+9x^4-5x^2+1}{x^{12}-10x^{10}+37x^8-42x^6+26x^4-8x^2+1}\,{dx} $$

The answer is $\pi/2$ ([formula 34](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DefiniteIntegral.html)). How does one calculate this?

EDIT: I don't know complex analysis. I traced the problem back to a book but the book used complex analysis. I should have said that from the start, sorry.

Comment: What is your background? Do you know complex analysis?

Comment: note that the integrand is equal to $$1/4\,{\frac {-{x}^{5}-4\,{x}^{4}-3\,{x}^{3}+4\,{x}^{2}+5\,x+2}{{x}^{6}
+4\,{x}^{5}+3\,{x}^{4}-4\,{x}^{3}-2\,{x}^{2}+2\,x+1}}+1/4\,{\frac {{x}
^{5}-4\,{x}^{4}+3\,{x}^{3}+4\,{x}^{2}-5\,x+2}{{x}^{6}-4\,{x}^{5}+3\,{x
}^{4}+4\,{x}^{3}-2\,{x}^{2}-2\,x+1}}
$$

Comment: You asked a [very similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1587694/73025) 4 hours ago and got a great answer. What's the point of this one?

Comment: @Startwearingpurple: That integral was also discussed some years back in [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/267265/4781).

Comment: @I.Cavey, No, I don't know complex analysis.

Comment: @Startwearingpurple I want to learn the techniques to solve these kind of problems. I tried the technique I was taught by that beautiful solution on this integral and many other things but none worked for me.

Comment: The previous version of this Question also includes an Answer based on rational decomposition, although it is not perhaps as detailed as you would like.  It might be best to keep everything in one place by adding a further Answer there rather than reopening this one.