# Difficult to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)}{(x^3+2x^2-x-1)^2+(x^2+x-1)^2}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

Where $a,b$ and $c$ are consecutive arithmetic terms.

We wish to evaluate this integral,

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)}{(x^3+2x^2-x-1)^2+(x^2+x-1)^2}\mathrm dx$$

I don't even really know how to make an attempt.

If I expanded the denominator it is very messy.

I can't factorise $x^3+2x^2-x-1$ or $x^2+x-1.$

Comment: The denominator of your integrand $${x}^{6}+4\,{x}^{5}+3\,{x}^{4}-4\,{x}^{3}-4\,{x}^{2}+2$$ has only complex roots.

Comment: Maple says your integral is infinity

Comment: It cannot be infinity. The denominator is always positive and acts like $x^6$ when $x\to\pm\infty$, numerator goes like $x^4$,  integral of $1/x^2$ converges on $x\to\pm\infty$

Comment: Integral is $(3 - a - b - c + a b  + a c + b c) \pi$, but I need some time to explain why

Comment: Is this some kind of contest problem? Can you share the source of it?

Comment: @VasilyMitch It's just that $$x(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)=(abc)x + (ab+bc+ac)x^2 +(a+b+c)x^3+x^4$$ And the information about the consecutive arithmetic terms is useless as it holds for any numbers. Let $p(x)$ to be the denominator, then:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{p(x)}dx=0,\quad \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2}{p(x)}dx=\pi,\quad \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^3}{p(x)}dx=-\pi,\quad \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^4}{p(x)}dx=3\pi $$
My belief is that it's just another case of this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2821162/515527. Finding what substitution was made, is quite hard though.

Comment: @Zacky, Yeah, I took it with residues. But I can't explain how to take those without Mathematica. They seem magical. I will think about your link. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is an adaption of my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2611917/257943), many similar evaluations are also given there.

---

Two reasons enable the integral to evaluate nicely:

- Firstly reason: the denominator $(x^3+2x^2-x-1)^2+(x^2+x-1)^2$
  factors as $$\underbrace{\left(x^3+(2-i) x^2-(1+i)
     x+(-1+i)\right)}_{h_1(x)} \underbrace{\left(x^3+(2+i) x^2-(1-i)
     x+(-1-i)\right)}_{h_2(x)}$$
- Second reason: roots of $h_1$ all lie in upper plane, denote them by
  $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$.

Now residue theorem implies
$$\frac{1}{{2\pi i}}\int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\frac{{p(x)}}{{{h_1}(x){h_2}(x)}}dx}  = \frac{{p(\alpha )}}{{{h_1}'(\alpha ){h_2}(\alpha )}} + \frac{{p(\beta )}}{{{h_1}'(\beta ){h_2}(\beta )}} + \frac{{p(\gamma )}}{{{h_1}'(\gamma ){h_2}(\gamma )}}$$

The RHS is a symmetric function in $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$, roots of $h_1 \in \mathbb{Q}(i)[x]$. If $p(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, then without any computation, we know that
$$\frac{1}{{2\pi i}}\int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\frac{{p(x)}}{{{h_1}(x){h_2}(x)}}dx} \in \mathbb{Q}(i)$$
since the integral is real, $\frac{1}{\pi }\int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\frac{{p(x)}}{{{h_1}(x){h_2}(x)}}dx} \in \mathbb{Q}$. This explains the nice result. The rational number can be explicitly calculated via elementary symmetric polynomials, a cumbersome but mechanical process, the results for $p(x) = x,x^2,x^3,x^4$ are already pointed out in comment.

Answer (score 3):

I will show the calculation of (On upper plane)
$$\sum_r Res\left(\frac{x}{h(x)},r\right)=0,\quad
\sum_r Res\left(\frac{x^2}{h(x)},r\right)=\frac{1}{2i},\quad 
\sum_r Res\left(\frac{x^3}{h(x)},r\right)= -\frac{1}{2i},\quad 
\sum_r Res\left(\frac{x^4}{h(x)},r\right)=\frac{3}{2i} $$
using formula $Res(f,r)=\frac{g(r)}{h'(r)}$

---

Denominator $$h(x)=(x^3+2x^2-x-1)^2+(x^2+x-1)^2 \\ =((x^3 + 2 x^2 - x - 1) - i (x^2 + x - 1))((x^3 + 2 x^2 - x - 1) + i (x^2 + x - 1))$$

Numeric calculation show that all root(all roots are simple) in upper plane is given by $$(x^3 + 2 x^2 - x - 1) - i (x^2 + x - 1)=0$$
So if $r$ is a root of $$(x^3 + 2 x^2 - x - 1) - i (x^2 + x - 1)$$
Then $$r^3 = -(2-i) r^2+(1+i) r+(1-i)$$
Let $S=-(2-i),J=-(1+i),P=(1-i)$, Vieta's formulas will be applied later.

Derivative of denominator is given by $$6 x^5+20 x^4+12 x^3-12 x^2-8 x$$
Note that $$Res(f,r)=\frac{r^n}{6 r^5+20 r^4+12 r^3-12 r^2-8 r}\\
=\frac{r^{n-1}}{6 r^4+20 r^3+12 r^2-12 r-8}$$
Using $r^3 = -(2-i) r^2+(1+i) r+(1-i)$ we can always reduces polynomial of r to degree not greater than $2$, i.e.:
$$
6 r^4+20 r^3+12 r^2-12 r-8=(6 - 2 i) - (4 - 8 i) r - (4 - 2 i) r^2 
$$
The denominator of 
$$\sum_{r=A,B,C} \frac{g(r)}{(6 - 2 i) - (4 - 8 i) r - (4 - 2 i) r^2 }$$
is given by
$$
(52 + 36 i) \\
-(88-16 i) A-(88-16 i) B-(88-16 i) C \\
-(40 + 20 i) A^2 - (40 + 20 i) B^2 - (40 + 20 i) C^2 \\
+(72 - 104 i) A B + (72 - 104 i) A C + (72 - 104 i) B C \\
+(60 - 20 I) A^2 B + (60 - 20 I) A B^2 + (60 - 20 i) A C^2 + (60 - 
    20 i) B C^2 + (60 - 20 i) A^2 C + (60 - 20 i) B^2 C\\
+(30 + 10 i) A^2 B^2 + (30 + 10 i) A^2 C^2 + (30 + 10 i) B^2 C^2 \\
-(40 - 80 i) A^2 B C - (40 - 80 i) A B^2 C - (40 - 80 i) A B C^2 \\
-(40 - 20 i) A^2 B^2 C - (40 - 20 i) A B^2 C^2 - (40 - 20 i) A^2 B C^2\\
+(32 + 176 i) A B C \\
-(22 + 4 i) A^2 B^2 C^2
$$
which is equal to
$$
 (52 + 36 i) - (88 - 16 i) S - (40 + 20 i) (S^2 - 2 J) + (72 - 
    104 i) J + (60 - 20 i) (S J - 3 P) + (30 + 10 i) (J^2 - 
    2 P S) - (40 - 80 i) P S - (40 - 20 i) P J + (32 + 
    176 i) P - (22 + 4 i) P^2 \\
=56 + 16 i
$$
When $g(r)=1$, the numerator is given by
$$
(18 + 24 i)\\
-(28 + 4 i) A - (28 + 4 i) B - (28 + 4 i) C \\
-(10 + 10 i) A^2 - (10 + 10 i) B^2 - (10 + 10 i) C^2 \\
+(16 - 12 i) A B + (16 - 12 i) B C + (16 - 12 i) A C \\
+(4 + 3 i) B^2 C^2 + (4 + 3 i) A^2 C^2 + (4 + 3 i) A^2 B^2 \\
+10 A^2 B + 10 A B^2 + 10 A^2 C + 10 B^2 C + 10 A C^2 + 10 B C^2
$$
which is equal to 
$$
(18 + 24 i) - (28 + 4 i) S - (10 + 10 i) (S^2 - 2 J) + (16 - 
    12 i) J + (4 + 3 i) (J^2 - 2 P S) + 10 (S J - 3 P) \\
=0
$$
When $g(r)=r$, the numerator is given by
$$
(6 + 8 i) A + (6 + 8 i) B + (6 + 8 i) C\\
-(28 + 4 i) A B - (28 + 4 i) A C - (28 + 4 i) B C\\
-(5 + 5 i) A^2 B - (5 + 5 i) A B^2 - (5 + 5 i) A^2 C - (5 + 
    5 i) B^2 C - (5 + 5 i) A C^2 - (5 + 5 i) B C^2\\
+(48 - 36 i) A B C\\
+20 A^2 B C + 20 A B^2 C + 20 A B C^2\\
+(4 + 3 i) A^2 B^2 C + (4 + 3 i) A^2 B C^2 + (4 + 3 i) A B^2 C^2
$$
which is equal to 
$$
(6 + 8 i) S - (28 + 4 i) J - (5 + 5 i) (S J - 3 P) + (48 - 36 i) P + 
 20 S P + (4 + 3 i) P J\\
=8 - 28 i
$$
When $g(r)=r^2$, the numerator is given by
$$
(6 + 8 i) A^2 + (6 + 8 i) B^2 + (6 + 8 i) C^2 \\
-(14 + 2 i) A^2 B - (14 + 2 i) A B^2 - (14 + 2 i) A^2 C -(14 + 2 i) B^2 C - (14 + 2 i) A C^2 - (14 + 2 i) B C^2\\
-(10 + 10 i) A^2 B^2 - (10 + 10 i) A^2 C^2 - (10 + 10 i) B^2 C^2 \\
+(16 - 12 i) A^2 B C + (16 - 12 i) A B^2 C + (16 - 12 i) A B C^2 \\
+20 A^2 B^2 C + 20 A^2 B C^2 + 20 A B^2 C^2\\
+(12 + 9 i) A^2 B^2 C^2\\
$$
which is equal to
$$
(6 + 8 i) (S^2 - 2 J) - (14 + 2 i) (S J - 3 P) - (10 + 10 i) (J^2 - 
    2 P S) + (16 - 12 i) S P + 20 P J + (12 + 9 i) P^2\\
=-8 + 28 i
$$
The result followed by togethering all the things.