# Find $\int\limits^{\infty}_{0}\frac{1}{(x^8+5x^6+14x^4+5x^2+1)^4}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

I was asked to prove that

$$\int\limits^{\infty}_{0}\frac{1}{(x^8+5x^6+14x^4+5x^2+1)^{4}}dx=\pi\frac{14325195794+(2815367209\sqrt{26})}{14623232(9+2\sqrt{26})^\frac{7}{2}}$$

I checked the result numerically and the first digits correct using W|F

$$\int\limits^{\infty}_{0}\frac{1}{(x^8+5x^6+14x^4+5x^2+1)^4}dx\approx 0.19874620328$$

I tried to start with trig substitution but the high power in the integral make it more complicated. Is there any way to evaluate this integral?

Comment: That can be tackled through the residue theorem with the same technique shown here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266181/a-nasty-integral-of-a-rational-function

Comment: Anyway, who asked you that is a bit of a sadist :D

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio he is my Mathematics professor  :). I don't know how he get this  horrible integral

Comment: My bet is on a Chinese mathematical competition. Anyway, the question ultimately boils down to writing $x^8+5x^6+14 x^4+5x^2+1$ as a sum of two squares, see my other answer. The fourth power is not a huge complication.

Comment: Could be Indian too...

Comment: russian maybe??

Comment: @tired I admit that most of the hardest integrals comes from Russia, but not this one because my professor is Egyptian also I am not sure if this integral is made by him or not.

Comment: $y^4+5y^3+14y^2+5y+1=(y^2+\frac{1}{2}(5+\sqrt{23}i)y+1)(y^2+\frac{1}{2}(5-\sqrt{23}i)y+1)$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint**. A route.

One may recall the following result, which goes back at least to G. Boole (1857).

> **Proposition**. Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and let $f$ be an *even* function. Then
>   $$
> \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^{2n}f\left(x-\frac1x\right) dx=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(n+k)!}{(2k)!(n-k)!}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^{2k}f(x)\: dx.  \tag1
> $$

Then one may write
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(x^8+5x^6+14x^4+5x^2+1)^{4}}\:dx
\\\\&=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{x^{-16}}{\left(\left(x^4+\dfrac1{x^4}\right)+5\left(x^2+\dfrac1{x^2}\right)+14\right)^{4}}\:dx
\\\\&=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{x^{-16}}{\left(\left[\left(x-\dfrac1x\right)^2+2\right]^2+5\left(x-\dfrac1x\right)^2+22\right)^{4}}\:dx
\\\\&=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{x^{14}}{\left(\left[\left(x-\dfrac1x\right)^2+2\right]^2+5\left(x-\dfrac1x\right)^2+22\right)^{4}}\:dx \qquad \left(x \to \dfrac1x \right)
\\\\&=\frac12\int\limits^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{x^{14}}{\left(\left[\left(x-\dfrac1x\right)^2+2\right]^2+5\left(x-\dfrac1x\right)^2+22\right)^{4}}\:dx
\\\\&=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^7 \frac{(7+k)!}{(2k)!(7-k)!}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{x^{2k}}{\left(\left(x^2+2\right)^2+5x^2+22\right)^{4}}\:dx \qquad (\text{using}\,\,(1))
\\\\&=\sum_{k=0}^7 \frac{(7+k)!}{(2k)!(7-k)!}\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^{2k}}{\left(x^4+6x^2+26\right)^{4}}\:dx
\\\\&=\pi\:\frac{14325195794+(2815367209\sqrt{26})}{14623232(9+2\sqrt{26})^\frac{7}{2}}
\end{align}
$$ where we have concluded by using **Theorem** $3.1$ (p.$6$) [here](http://129.81.170.14/~vhm/papers_html/amseps.pdf), in G. Boros and V. Moll's paper.

Comment: Awesome solution sir O. Oloa. (+1). Just question. is there a proof for the Proposition?

Comment: +1. Unexpected and quite fine. I was thinking in the factor $x + x^{-1}$ but I didn't go further.

Comment: Nice answer and interesting ref! (+1)